# Is my 2-year UK visa still valid if I haven't used it within the first 6 months of validity?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, multiple-entry

Almost five months ago I was issued with a 2-year multiple-entry visa to the UK on business and a short-family holiday.

For almost 6 months I have not been able to travel. I intend making this trip in December but I would also like to find out whether my UK visa can be cancelled if I do. Or travel with it in the first 6 months after it has been issued.

Answer (score 2):

Your visa is valid during its whole validity period.

However, if, for example, only using it close to its expiry, the officers may well want to know the reason for that, and depending on your explanation, could suspect some sort of fraud on your part.

To be safe, if possible being documentation (even social media conversations could be useful) proving why you got the visa so early without being able to use it straight away.

Answer (score 1):

The [UK Government website](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) doesn't make any mention of validity being restricted so your visa should still be valid. If you're in any doubt you should contact the visa centre where you applied and ask the question.