# UK visa issuance date

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

Please kindly confirm if I can still travel with my visa. I have a five-year UK visa but have not traveled to the UK for 3 years. Can I still travel with the visa? I understand that there is a new policy that states that one must travel after two weeks of visa issuance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106488/is-my-2-year-uk-visa-still-valid-if-i-havent-used-it-within-the-first-6-months

Answer (score 3):

You have a five-year visa, but have been out of the UK for 3 continuous years. You want to know if you can still use your visa for travel.

No, you are no longer able to use your visa to enter the UK. All UK visas, including "Indefinite Leave to Remain" expire after two years outside of the UK.  The controlling technical reference is [Paragraph 20 of the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk) (*emphasis mine*).

> The leave of a person whose stay in the United Kingdom is subject to a time limit lapses on his going to a country or territory outside the common travel area if the leave was given for a period of six months or less or conferred by a visit visa. In other cases, **leave lapses on the holder remaining outside the United Kingdom for a continuous period of more than two years.**

The rule goes on to state that it is possible to ask for an exemption:

> His application to re-enter the United Kingdom should be considered in the light of all the relevant circumstances.

While it may be possible, it may not be practical, as you would be pleading your case at the border and, should the authorities not find in your favor, you would be sent back to your originating or home country.

You also wrote:

> I understand that there is a new policy that states that one must travel after two weeks of visa issuance.

This has to do with those who must collect [Biometric Residence Permits](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits) from a Post Office or similar agency. Based on what you wrote, it is not relevant to your situation and what you heard is stated inaccurately in any case.

Comment: Wonder why the hell the hotline didn't tell me this. Thanks for the reference

Comment: @Coke .. you know what hotline info can be like :) While an airline might not question the visa, UK border surely would make it difficult for the individual, as you pointed out to OP.

Answer (score 1):

Called the UKVI, and the two-week rule of which you speak does not exist.

However, as stated in the other answer, not having used your visa in two years effectively renders it invalid.

In any case, not having used your visa shortly after obtaining it may well invoke suspicion regarding your purpose of travel, so in such cases, the traveller should bring any and all documentation proving why they never went to the UK shortly after having applied for and received the visa.